# User for mysql database

Tags: root, mysql

On a test Debian server, I'm using `root` as user for mysql. Then for each Wordpress site I have, I have this in the php config file:

```
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '...');
```

Is this "root user" a mysql-specific thing, or is it related to Linux root user?

If so, what's the best practice for separating mysql from `root` user (for security concerns)?

Comment: This belongs to [database SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). In short, root in mysql comes from the Unix terminology, where root is an administrator; the same goes for mysql(although you could name it whatever you like). Database security concerns should either be asked on database SE, or [Information security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this post is better suited for database SE.

Comment: The mysql root account and the system root account are not related.

Comment: Ok. Instead of just closing and downvoting, could we move it to database SE ? (I imagine only a mod can do it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root` user in *mySQL* is not the same `root`of  *GNU/Linux*. Is an user created **inside** the database manager to access it. You must avoid to use it, you can create users with restricted privileges easily and in that way prevent security risks.

Answer (score 1):

That's the `root` user for MySQL. It has nothing to do with the Linux `root` user. Just like its Linux counterpart, it's the name of the superuser account on MySQL.

You should not use `root` as the MySQL user for your Wordpress database, that's a big security risk. Create a MySQL user `wp` (or whatever) for it, then give him access only to the `wordpress` database.